# What is the membership data?

Tags: civievent

I have logged in to CIvCRM for the first time to interrogate the membership data of my local Green party but I don't know how to find that data.
Can you advise me?
Jim

Answer (score 1):

Jim, Welcome CiviCRM SE. You can use membership search to find membership data or reports.

Search:
CiviCRM >> Membership >> Find Memberships.

Reports:
CiviCRM >> Reports >> Membership Reports.

Doc:
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/what-is-civimember/

Cheers

Pradeep